# Rollbacks should trigger CAPTCHA

Tags: feature-request, usability, captcha, rollback-wars

From [this UserVoice suggestion](https://web.archive.org/web/20090316091304/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/125639-rollbacks-should-trigger-captcha):

When a user edits a tag, or edits a question, the CAPTCHA is invoked after multiple short timeframe edits. However, if a user simply hits 'rollback', he can rollback as many entries as he wants (I've done it on 25 and not had an issue) without triggering CAPTCHA.

**Desired Behavior**: I think this behavior should be changed to invoke CAPTCHA for "Rollback" much like it does for "Edit".

Comment: noooo not more captchas :(

Comment: I'm with Elliot on this.

Comment: [Some historical background](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/)(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds reasonable enough and it could also be thought of as a potential short cool-off period to prevent rollback wars as well.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why you would want to do that.

The reason why excessive posting and editing triggers CAPTCHAs is to stop spammers. Rollbacks, by nature, can't exactly be used well for spamming.

Comment: I don't know if you were around when Rollback wars were king (and there are still tag wars, though edits less so); but authors would rollback edits and not have to pay any sort of penalty for doing so, so you could have two determined users both rolling back edits they didn't agree with, instead of achieving consent.

Comment: I don't think CAPTCHAs is the solution to that.

Comment: The opposite is the solution. Make them freehand draw "I will not engage in rollback wars." one hundred times.

Comment: @TCPMAN.EXE After marking 20 other people's individual lines as written correctly or incorrectly. If they [answered [more than 1] opposite to [a 75% majority of [users who reviewed that specific drawing]]], they would have to write twice the number of lines, after doing another review. Failing the criteria often enough would cause them to do twice as many again and again until it was physically impossible for them to send so many thousands of images across the internet. And then we will have won.